# How to return true/false to Get-WindowsOptionalFeature on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to check if a Windows Feature is installed or not, before install, to avoid reinstall.

I'm using this  to check:

```
function Check-WindowsFeature {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FeatureName 
    )  
  if((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName $FeatureName -Online) -Like "Enabled") {
        # $FeatureName is Installed
        # (simplified function to paste here)
    } else {
        # Install $FeatureName 
    }
  }
}
```

But "if" always return false, even when feature is installed.
Example:

```
C:\> (Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online) -Like "Enabled"
False

C:\> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online | ft -Property State
State
-----
Enabled
```

I already tried format as table, format as wide, filter with `-Property State`, output as string, match with regex, match with `-eq`and `contains` and none works.

Function get `$FeatureName` fine, 'cause install works.

How to make this work?

Comment: Your second command line uses `-Property State`, and that property is apparently either *Enabled* or *Disabled*. Why doesn't your PS code check the value of `State` as well?

Comment: `((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V-All -Online) | ft -Property State) -Like "Enabled"` returns nothing

Comment: Who said anything about using `LIKE`? You're checking for equality.

Comment: I'm tried use `contains`and `-eq` too, as described, they didn't work. 
@jisaak explained why below.

Comment: @jisaak said exactly what I said (but much better). Use an equality test to check State.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because the return value of [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=289358) is a `AdvancedFeatureObject`. You can't use the `-Like` on that object with an string.

You instead have to access the property `State` on that object and compare that:

```
function Check-WindowsFeature {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string]$FeatureName 
    )  
  if((Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName $FeatureName -Online).State -eq "Enabled") {
        # $FeatureName is Installed
        # (simplified function to paste here)
    } else {
        # Install $FeatureName 
    }
  }
```

By the way, I would change the name of the function to something like `Install-WindowsFeatureIfNotInstalled` because I wouldn't expect a function with `Check` verb to install anything on my machine

Comment: Ohhh... I never would have known about it. Works now, thanks!
I'll put your name (and the link for this answer) on my PS repo at Github.

Comment: About edit: It's a internal function to install development dependencies, but i put a note to warning this will install if not already installed. :)